# Coroutine Scope, Suspend and withContext inquiries

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have 3 snippet below

1. Just scope launch

```
    fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { runMe() }
    fun rumMe() = doSomething()
```

2. scope launch with suspend

```
    fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { runMe() }
    suspend fun rumMe() = doSomething()
```

3. scope launch with suspend and withContext

```
    fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { runMe() }
    suspend fun rumMe() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { doSomething() }
```

I see them being launch in a different thread from the Main, and is run asynchronously not blocking the main thread.

I wonder what's their different? If they are all the same, then 1 is best. If not, when should I use 2 or 3?

I tried reading this, and can't get it clearly https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and 2 are the same. You have to add `suspend` modifier to your function only if it does something with coroutines.

The difference between the first and the third cases:

```
fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
    // io thead executor
    runMe()
}
// still io thread executor
fun rumMe() = doSomething()

fun main() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
    // io thead executor
    runMe()
}
suspend fun rumMe() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { 
    // default/cpu thead executor
    doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Understood that. But 1 and 3 is still no different if we just want it to execute in a different thread, right?

Comment: My experiment printing the thread using `${Thread.currentThread()}` shows that for case 3, within the `launch` and within the `withContext` has the same thread.

Comment: Yep, if you want just to not use the main thread then there is no sense to use the third snippet.

Comment: looks like `Dispatchers.IO` and `Dispatchers.Default` shares treads https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/7699a20982c83d652150391b39567de4833d4253/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Dispatchers.kt (at the end of the file) You can change `Dispatchers.Default` to `newSingleThreadContext("test")`to see the difference in `${Thread.currentThread()}`

Answer (score 1):

By adding `suspend` modifier to a function, you allow the function to use another suspending functions. For example, if the `runMe()` function would use suspending [delay](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) it's reasonable to make that function suspendable. See [Your first coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#your-first-coroutine) documentation section.

Another major difference of suspending functions over ordinary ones, is that the suspending functions [are cancellable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative). Let's look at the Android example:

```
class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel() {
  init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      val firstPart = loadFirstPartOfData()
      val secondPart = loadSecondPartOfData(firstPart)
      ...
    }
  }

  suspend loadFirstPartOfData() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }

  suspend loadSecondPartOfData(firstPartOfData: FirstPartOfData) {
    // some UI thread safe calculations
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // network request here
    }
  }
}
```

Imagine that the view (Android Activity) loads the data to display it. If the Activity is closed before the second part of data is loaded, it's wasteful to load the second part. But, because the `loadSecondPartOfData()` function is suspending, it checks whether the scope is active or not, and the function won't be executed if the scope isn't active.

Also notice how the functions use `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. The functions are called from `viewModelScope.launch`, which by default uses `Dispatchers.Main` (UI thread), but it's safe to call the functions from UI thread because the execution context is explicitly selected by the functions. It's the right way to write suspending functions, when you don't worry about the current thread when you call a function. It's regarding your third question.

In your example, the first snippet will work, but in a real app, as usual, things become a little bit more complex.

Comment: Just to clarify, the function is cancelable, not because of the `suspend` keyword, but due to the use of some of the suspending function e.g. `withContext`